# Is there a reason why Ignored tags are, well, not really ignored?

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags

I understand that this is a question regarding the entire StackExchange network, but recently this annoyance of mine has been considerably elevated because of Skyrim.

I like the idea of being able to ignore tags, and I guess it makes sense to be able to see them under certain circumstances, yet be marked as ignored.  However, I would really like for there to be a way in which I can completely hide (or filter) tags from my ignore list.

As mentioned in my opening sentence, Skyrim is my current annoyance.  I have it set to ignore but there have been times where sorting all new questions by post date have had only 1 or 2 in the list that were not associated with Skyrim.

I'm glad that people are interested in the game and want to ask questions.  It's good for the site.  However, it's making the site considerably annoying for those of us who don't care about the game.

Also, if you're thinking that it's not a big deal and that all of those Skyrim tags will dwindle soon, that may be true but that doesn't mean that there won't be another game in the future that is just as popular as Skyrim.  At that time, the same problem will apply.  For those of us who are not interested in the game.

I'm not trying to complain.  I'm just asking if there is way to filter out these questions or if the system can be updated so that ignored tags are hidden and not just discolored?

Comment: I think there's also a Meta request to have a "quick" option for hiding/unhiding them from the questions list. I know it's not directly what you're asking for, but it sounds like a convenience you might like. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Here we go - [this is the Meta question I was thinking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags). It's a fair bit old, but every vote counts. ♪

Comment: +1, agreed.  I'd also like to avoid spoilers about the game (since I intend to play it someday) so I likewise have it marked as ignored.  The grayed out background doesn't help much to hide spoilers.  I'll probably try the prefs option suggested below next, although that's still not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered marking the "Hide ignored tags" option under `prefs` on your profile page? This will hide the actual posts from view.

Now, this is client-side, so it happens after the selection of questions have been displayed. Which means that you'll still only have the handful of non-such-tagged questions. However, you'll be able to look at them without a humongous bunch of faded out questions in the middle. Browsing through the `Questions` list is still much easier in this scenario.

Comment: Sometimes this means that the homepage will only show five questions. :p

Comment: @Ullallulloo For now, "sometimes" is a bit of an understatement, dontcha think? ♪

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that.  I figured there had to be a setting and I was just missing it.

Comment: Is this a preference that needs/can be set up separately for each Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @stars It needs to be setup separately, but I believe we're working on a change to make it default to "hidden" first.

Answer (score 3):

Right now this hidden page seems to fit your requirements:

### https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=interesting

I've got quite the hefty ignore list (although I do *not* always hide ignored posts!), and in this page I get no question with ignored tag. The server still populated the page with the correct amount of questions, and indeed the bottom one for me was last active "nov 11 at 13:42" (!)

Comment: Actually, ignored tags *are* completely dropped on SO's *Interesting* view - "[The homepage will] drop questions containing any of your ignored tags", from http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/